# Copying visible contents of one cell in an Excel workbook to another

Tags: python

This is my first Stackoverflow question and I am also a newbie at coding so apologies if I did it wrong.

I wrote the following code in order to copy the visible contents of one cell in an Excel workbook to another. However, when I run the code it copies *text:'cell a1 file'* to file2. Is there a way to copy only the data contained within the quotation marks?

```
import xlutils
import xlrd
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
os.chdir("*PATH*")
workbook_handler = xlrd.open_workbook("file.xls")
sheet_handler = workbook_handler.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
cell_handler = sheet_handler.cell(0,0)
readbook = open_workbook("file2.xls")
writebook = copy(readbook)
sheet = writebook.get_sheet(0)
sheet.write(0,0,str(cell_handler))
writebook.save("file2.xls")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

```
cell_handler = sheet_handler.cell(0,0)
```

returns more than just the cell value whereas

```
cell_handler = sheet_handler.cell_value(0,0)
```

will return only the value contained in the cell.